# Java: Searching an array by a variable in an instance of object

Tags: java, arrays, search

Overall goal is to create a library simulation that allows searches for books as well as transactions eg to borrow a book. I've only included the parts I think are relevant.

I have the array `stock` in the `Biblio` class as follows:

```
public class Biblio{
    private ArrayList<Book> stock;
```

and the `Book` class with the constructor:

```
    public Book(String author , String title)
    {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title ;
        code = null;//this is a String

    }
```

In the main method I am trying to search for a Book object using the `code` (which is `String`), I am using the `findCode` method in the `Biblio` class:

```
    public Book findCode(String searchedCode){
        Book foundBook = null;
        for(Book bookObj : stock){

            if(bookObj.getCode().equxals(searchedCode)){
                 bookObj= foundBook;}//
        return foundBook;
    }
```

and here is the code in the main method I currently have:

```
 Biblio libSim;
 libSim = generateLib();                            
                                   ...
System.out.println(libSim.findCode(scan.next()));
```

but the output is coming up as null and I think it is because the `foundBook` equals null. However I can't return `bookObj`.

I do not know how I can find an object in an array by searching for the `code` variable. The books are added to the library in another method and using a setter method I have set any `code` that equals `null` to a string with the format `LIB0001`, this is done before I call the `findCode` method.

**How do you find an object by searching the array for a specific instance variable?**

Comment: the question isn't how do I compare strings, it is how do I find an object in an array by comparing instance variables of the objects? When I use .equals() I still have issues making it work.

Comment: I have an answer using lambdas; I'd love to post it.  Too bad.

Comment: that wouldn't be an answer I can use.

Comment: Yes it is. Maybe not today, but....  This is JDK 8. You should try it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare Strings with ==

see here on how to do it properly: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Didn't know it wasn't possible. However I did originally have `.equals()`, but its up the warning 'object equals null is never true',

Comment: You have to use equals because String is an object. It is different than int or double.

Comment: I have .equals() originally but this never worked for me either, the question isn't how do I compare strings, it is how do I find an object in an array by comparing instance variables of the objects?

Comment: Your algorithm should work if you use equals(). Your algorithm is a simple for loop. If you use equals() it should work absolutely fine.

Comment: It doesn't. I am getting null pointer errors and have no idea why.

Comment: I think I see your problem. 1) use equals() and 2) in the for loop you say bookObj = foundBook when it should be "foundBook = bookObj"

Comment: 1) fixed, 2) fixed. However the null pointer issue seems to be with             `if(selectedBook.getCode().equals(null)){`, apparently the object equals null is never true, but when assigining values to `code`, only some objects are assigned values, so there should be cases of `code=null`